# Python Jinja error while comparing string

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm getting a problem while comparing two string in python:

**this is working:**

```
{% for publication in publications %}
        {{ publications[publication].pub_type }}
{% endfor %}
```

but not this:

```
{% for publication in publications %}
        {% if publications[publication].pub_type equals "conference_paper" %} 
             class="active" 
         {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

In the above code, I'm just testing something, but its not working

I'm getting this error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError
TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got 'equals'
```

Comment: does it work if you replace the first "conference_paper" with a real variable?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

perhaps you want:

```
{% if publication.pub_type == "conference_paper" %}
{#                         ^^                    #}
```

`equals` is not [valid jinja2 syntax](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/switching/#conditions)

Comment: Seems unlikely, since that's an awfully verbose way to write "`if True`" (which itself is an awfully verbose way to not write a conditional at all) in a template.

Comment: I guess the documentation is wrong, lol, http://wsgiarea.pocoo.org/jinja/docs/conditions.html

Comment: @GangstaGraham: I believe that documentation refers to jinja, not jinja2, they are similar but only jinja2 is currently supported.

Comment: Haha, I guess I was looking at the wrong docs, thanks for this answer by the way, it helped. :)